# How do I rearrange font styles in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, styles

I have a custom font style in Microsoft Word named **Important**. For convenience, I have the font style saved to the **Quick Styles** gallery. (See [*Add and remove styles from the Quick Styles gallery*)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-and-remove-styles-from-the-Quick-Styles-gallery-21C5B9DE-B19E-4575-BC87-CB2B55ECE224#ID0EAABAAA=2010,_2007)

[image: List of font styles]

The new style saved to the first space in my **Styles** toolbar, ahead of more commonly used styles like **Normal**, **Heading**, and **Title**.

I would like to rearrange my styles so **Important** is further to the right, as I do not plan on using it very often.

[image: Mockup of ideal style arrangement]

**Is it possible to rearrange font styles in Microsoft Word 2010?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adapted from *[Shauna Kelley - How to control the Quick Styles gallery on the Home tab in Word](http://shaunakelly.com/word/styles/quick-styles-gallery.html)*

---

***Instructions apply to Word 2007 and Word 2010***

1. Select the **Home** tab and open the **Styles** pane with the launcher button in the bottom-right of the Styles group.

   - Alternatively, you can use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

[image: Show styles window]

2. At the bottom of the Styles pane, click the **Manage Styles** button.

[image: Manage styles button]

3. In the Manage Styles dialog, click the **Recommend** tab.

[image: Recommend tab]

4. Make sure the **Sort Order** is set to **As Recommended**

[image: Sort order]

5. Search through the list and select the style you want to rearrange.

[image: Selecting style in list]

6. Use the **Assign Value** button to give the style a priority between 1 and 99. This will determine the position in the **Quick Styles** gallery.

   - Styles with the same priority are sorted using alphabetical order.

[image: Set sort priority]

7. Click **OK** to apply your changes

[image: Select OK]